# switch themes xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to make an App with Xamarin.Android where I have a RadioGroup with all my themes. I am trying to change the theme when the certain RadioButton from the group is checked, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why?

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:colorPrimary"> @color/blue</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground"> @color/grey</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent"> @color/yellow </item>
</style>

<style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary"> @color/green </item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark"> @color/blue </item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent"> @color/purple </item>      
     <item name="android:windowBackground"> @color/dark_blue </item>
</style>
</resources>
```

layout.axml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/errorMsg"
    android:onClick ="Change"
    android:id="@+id/radGrp">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Dark"
        android:id="@+id/radDark" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Light"
        android:id="@+id/radLight" />
</RadioGroup>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
RadioGroup radGrp = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.radGrp);
radGrp.CheckedChange += Change;

 private void Change(object sender, RadioGroup.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (e.CheckedId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.radDark: this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.DarkTheme); break;
                case Resource.Id.radLight: this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.LightTheme); break;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Do I need to change something in AndroidManifest.xaml or in the  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme=...  , MainLauncher = true)] ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation/feature of the way Themeing is implemented on Android. Changing an Activity's Theme doesn't actually take effect until the Activity runs OnResume, so effectively you have to re-start the activity. There are various strategies you can use to minimize the impact on the user. Xamarin actually provides a sample Theme Switcher app which might be a good reference for implementing something: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/ThemeSwitcher/

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of changing the text color? I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/material-theme , but here it doesn't say anything about how I can change the text color.

Comment: and one more thing. Is the best way to restart the activity with `Finish()` and `StartActivity(Intent)` ?

Comment: If you add:  <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item> to your style, then it will apply that color to the android:textColor attribute of every component that has that style applied (including if the style is used as a Theme)

Unfortunately, the Android Styling and Theming system is not well documented (and not that well implemented either IMO, but it is what it is).  I have added an answer below to explain it, in case you find yourself confused.

Answer (score 0):

## ***Themes and Styling***

Styling is the mechanism whereby the values assigned to properties/attributes are defined externally and then assigned to an object, which then applies them. This allows a single style definition to be applied to multiple objects, rather than having to define each property value for each object individually.

The use of styling ensures consistency in design within and across applications, reduces errors, and can save significant effort. It allows developers to quickly apply the overall visual design and concentrate on developing the value-added aspects of the application.

The styling system in Android is so tightly coupled into the Android ecosystem, that some things are impractical to achieve by any other mechanism, read some things you can’t do in code, only using the styling system  :-(

An Android style is an xml file that defines a set of property/attribute values. It can be targeted to a single class or multiple classes. Because it conforms to the xml standard, tags that are not relevant to an object are ignored by that object when applied to it.

Styling in Android can be applied at an application, activity, or object level.
From a technical perspective Themes and Styles are interchangeable. A Theme is just a Style applied at the Application or Activity level. The following should be used when referring to them:

- Style:   Defines a set of properties/attributes applied at the class
  and/or object level.
- Theme:   Defines a set of properties/attributes
  applied at the Application or Activity level.

Typically a Style used as a Theme will contain definitions for properties/attributes for many classes.

Styles (and therefore Themes) exhibit inheritance. A Style can inherit from another style, and then add and/or modify property/attribute values.

Styles (and the properties/attributes they define) are also applied hierarchically. In Android, the order of precedence is:

Property/attribute applied directly to an object     *> overrides >*     setting a property/attribute by applying a Style to an object      *> overrides >*    setting a property by applying a Theme (Style) to an Activity      *> overrides* >    setting a property by applying a Theme (Style) to an Application.

Android provides a number of predefined Styles for use as Themes. You can apply these as is or create your own Themes bases on them via inheritance. To support this, the Android styling system defines some styling attributes that these themes use and automatically apply across multiple objects. These includes things like colorPrimary, colorAccent, colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated, textColorSecondary etc. You can re-assign values to these in Styles so the new values are applied. You can also reference them in Styles, so you can pick up the values assigned to them in your applied Theme.

Lastly, different versions of Android may apply styling slightly differently (often due to changes in the properties/attributes of the objects), especially any styling system attributes. This is especially obvious between versions 4.4- and 5.0+ when Material Design was adopted. The support libraries address some of these inconsistencies, and each release of them seems to get slightly better, but if you need to support 4.4 and below, you will almost definitely find your self having to define some styles in both the values and the vales-v21 folders so they are applied appropriately to the different versions.